# Anexar uma foto ao email

Tags: android

Bom dia a todos, a duvida é a seguinte.
Tenho alguns campos básicos(nome, telefone etc), e uma opção para tirar fotos. Eu já tenho funcionando o envio de e-mail e o botão para tirar foto, consigo pegar os valores de todos os campos e tirar a foto inclusive, porem quero saber como que eu faço para anexar a foto neste e-mail...

Esses são os métodos para tirar a foto e salva-la no cartão de memoria do celular.

```
public void abrirCamera(){
        File picsDir =       Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File imageFile = new File(picsDir, "foto.jpg");
        Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(imageFile));
        startActivity(i);
    }

public void takePhoto(View view)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory
            (Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "Pic.jpg");

    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photo));
    imageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);

    startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {

        case TAKE_PICTURE:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                Uri selectedImage = imageUri;
                getActivity().getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null);

                ImageView imageView = (ImageView)  getActivity().findViewById(R.id.ImageView);

                ContentResolver cr = getActivity().getContentResolver();
                Bitmap bitmap;


                try {
                    bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr, selectedImage);

                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    fotoCart.setText("");
                    //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), selectedImage.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failed to load", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.e("Camera", e.toString());
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Pode adicionar algum trecho de código para ajudarmos a evolui-lo?

Comment: Esses métodos são vinculados a uma outra classe chamada Camera. Mas acho que é possível obter a foto sem ter de acessar essa outra classe...

Comment: E com Javamail? Tenho uma aplicação que fiz com Javamail!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você irá precisar ciar uma `Intent` colocando a `Uri` de sua foto como `EXTRA_STREAM`.

Tente algo parecido:

```
private void enviaEmail(Uri uriDaSuaFoto) {
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 

    //Definindo que o conteúdo sera uma imagem
    emailIntent.setType("application/image");

    //Qual e-mail a ser enviado
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "algum@email.com"); 

    //Titulo do e-mail
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Titulo"); 

    //Corpo do e-mail
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Corpo do email"); 

    //Aqui você coloca a uri da sua imagem
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriDaSuaFoto);

    //Criando um dialog para o usuário poder escolher qual aplicação enviar o e-mail
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Enviar e-mail com"));
}
```

Comment: Cara, muuuito obrigado me ajudou pra caramba... Deu tudo certo, vaaleu mesmo.